# Main domain & subdomains using the same files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

Lets say I have domain **domain.com**

and I want to make 3 subdomains using the same files as main domain

> sub1.domain.com
>
> sub2.domain.com
>
> sub3.domain.com

I want to show the same page in all of these subdomains but they have to work separately (without any redirects to main page) so I assume that I have to add some records to .htaccess in public_html? Should I create this subdomains in DA panel or just add some DNS records? should it be CNAME records?

I know I can make 3 subdomains and put the same files to all folders (sub1,sub2,sub3) but its stupid and I know its possible to make it easier.

Can you tell me what should I do in DA and what records add to htaccess, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not use rewrite, but rather:

Say you have

```
1. You are in Linux OS.
2. The main domain www.domain.com is in the directory DocumentRoot = /home/www .
```

You create symlink like this:

```
# cd /home
# ln -s ./www sub1 
# ln -s ./www sub2 
# ln -s ./www sub3
```

You have no hard copy of files, almost no hard disk usage is required.